# Hibernate One to many mapping with join table propertyaccessexception

Tags: hibernate, join, one-to-many

I have a one to many mapping with a join table.

```
class service{private Long service_id}
class codes{private Long code_id}
```

The service and code classes are setup as hibernate entities and they have mutators for their ids.

The join table

```
table servicecodes
(serviceid,
codeid);
```

My service class mapping:

```
<class name="path.to.Service" table="SERVICE"
lazy="false">

 <set name="sc" table="ServiceCodes">
    <key column="serviceid"/>
    <many-to-many column="codeid" unique="true"
        class="path.to.Codes"/>
 </set>
</class>
```

In my application layer I have:

```
serviceobj.set(Set<Codes>);
...
session.save(serviceobj);
```

At the session.save line, the following error is thrown:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection    getter of path.to.Codes.code_id
....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field path.to.Codes.code_id to java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out myself. The 'codes' class was setup with JPA annotations and the annotations were set on the property declarations. Setting the annotations on the getter methods of the entity's properties solved the issue.